# How to use liquid code in external Javascript in Shopify Order status page

Tags: javascript, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-liquid, shopifyscripts

I want to use shop and customer data in  Order status page using external JavaScrip.But I am not able to access liquid code

`Shopify.Checkout.OrderStatus.addContentBox(    "<h2>Feedback</h2>", "<p>customer: {{customer.first_name}}</p>" )`

Comment: Liquid is a template language that runs on the backend. Frontend JavaScript doesn't know what to do with it. If you want to get data to the frontend, then look into the [Shopify Ajax API](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/ajax) to communicate with the Shopify backend.